# Go to div + change tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode

I have a Tab menu (3 tabs) and I would like to find out, if there is a code that works like this: i press a button then i go automatically to the top of the site (for example "go to div" ) and automatically changes the Tab to second one?

Something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pictap.pl](http://pictap.pl/di-4EQIJBX5.gif))</sub>

Comment: you probably need to add some code instead of just an image.  Which cannot be seen btw...  Also, read the [ask] page to help you formulate a great question and elicit good answers

Comment: Look into scrollTop () for jquery, that will allow you to scroll up the page, changing the tab would just be a simple show/hide also in your click function. give it a shot and post your code with questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/ro0y3L3c/4/)

and pure code sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
font-family: sans-serif;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.movingmenu {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%; 
    position:absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 10%;
}
.tabmenu div {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tabmenu div.active {
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tabcontent2, .tabcontent3 {
display: none;  
}


#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #900;
}

#content1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #09C;
}

#content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FC6;

}

.gotobtn {
    background: #fff;
    color: purple;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content1"></div>
<div id="content2"></div>

<div class="movingmenu">
<div class="tabmenu">
<div>Tab 1</div>
<div>Tab 2</div>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu finibus libero. Nulla cursus tempor elit, id luctus nunc pulvinar aliquet. Sed luctus nibh nulla, ut sollicitudin turpis facilisis in. Quisque tempor blandit mi, in ultrices sapien hendrerit in. Sed aliquet, leo quis varius imperdiet, dolor justo vestibulum dui, at vulputate arcu nisl dictum libero. Phasellus eget convallis nibh, vel aliquam nisl. Vestibulum pretium est lacus, ac consectetur tellus vestibulum a. Praesent efficitur sollicitudin nisi. Maecenas id ante at ex semper placerat. Nunc in gravida arcu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In dictum, est sollicitudin lacinia luctus, urna magna malesuada nisi, et malesuada massa ipsum vel sapien. Integer vel interdum est. </div>
<div class="tabcontent2">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent egestas ex et lorem porta feugiat. Nullam pulvinar suscipit leo id posuere. Vestibulum placerat massa massa, a volutpat ex bibendum vitae. Cras hendrerit tortor est. Aliquam at semper purus, ut varius est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam at ex orci. Vivamus eget dignissim dolor, at hendrerit lacus. Nullam facilisis nunc vitae tincidunt interdum. </div>

<a href="#" data-ref="header" class="gotobtn">Odnosnik</a>
</div>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.gotobtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".movingmenu").animate({
        left: 0,
        top: 0
        }, 1000, function() { 
    $('.tabmenu div:last-child').addClass('active');
    $('.tabcontent1').hide();
    $('.tabcontent2').show();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx for answers I made it -[link](https://jsfiddle.net/t5wtx572/3/)  :))